# Remove listname from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I am receiving an API response in this format below. I am trying to filter through the list of dictionaries but I need to filter out(remove) the list key-"result" so that I can remain with a list of dictionaries for me to filter. Is there any way to do this?

```
{
"result": [
    {"x": 1},{ "x": 2},{"x": 3,}]}
```

This is what I am using to filter through the list of dictionaries but it wont work because of the list key "result". Any help will be appreciated.

```
keyValList = [1,2]
expectedResult = [d for d in response if d['x'] in keyValList]
```

Comment: `expectedResult = [d for d in response["result"] if d['x'] in keyValList]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you found this helpful I'll post an answer:

```
expectedResult = [d for d in response["result"] if d["x"] in keyValList]
```